# SQL get rows with similar data for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with ID (PK), fixed (integer) and a lot of other columns (name,content,comment,...)

When I create a version of my data I want to check if new or updated rows have a duplicate row with a fixed value of 1 or higher. (To edit rows with fixed values, you need more privileges)

```
ID | Fixed | name
1  | 1     | "john"
2  | 0     | "john" //new row
3  | 0     | "jane" // updated row
```

After creating a version history this should become:

```
ID | Fixed | name
1  | 2     | "john"
3  | 1     | "jane" 
4  | 0     | "john" //current row
5  | 0     | "jane" //current row
```

This query allows me to find the ID value of a "fixed" row for any of the new or updated rows (if I know their ID's beforehand).

```
select T.ID 
from MyTable T 
inner join (
      select name, 
      comments 
      from MyTable
      where ID = 2) E
on T.name = E.name 
and T.comments = E.comments 
where T.fixed = 1
```

This query works but I doubt it's the best solution.

I have the following questions/concerns:

1) I have to run this query for every new or updated row. Every time it will be comparing one row against all the other rows in the table. That isn't very efficient. Surely there is a better way?

2) can I search against all the ID's (2 and 3) in one query and return the matching ID's (or null if there isn't any)?

3) I should only compare the relevant data columns (e.g. name). Is there a way to select or inner join on all columns except some columns (ID, Fixed)?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can rewrite your query just as a join:

```
select T.ID 
from MyTable T inner join
     MyTable e
     on T.name = E.name and T.comments = E.comments and e.id = 2
where T.fixed = 1;
```

For performance, you want an index on `MyTable(fixed, name, comments, id)`.

If you want it to return a `NULL` value then use `left outer join`.  For a list, just use `in`:

```
select T.ID 
from MyTable T left outer join
     MyTable e
     on T.name = E.name and T.comments = E.comments and e.id in (2, 3)
where T.fixed = 1;
```

Comment: ID is created as integer primary key autoincrement. This makes it an index or doesn't it? I want to find a duplicate of a given row within the rows that a fixed value of 1 (or higher). Having an index won't help with that, will it?

Comment: @user965972 . . . A primary key automatically has a unique index on it (in effect).  However, the id can still be included in other indexes.

Comment: So I can and should create a non-unique index based of the name and comments (and the other data) columns (but not ID and fixed)? 


So instead of an inner join and searching against e.id, I should just search the table against the index id that represents e.id?